# Why does windows not show up in grub menu?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

I recently installed Ubuntu 17.04 on my Windows 7 laptop, intending to dual boot. However, now my computer automatically defaults to Ubuntu. After playing around, I got the grub menu to show, but it only shows Ubuntu. How do I get Windows to show?

Code: `sudo fdisk -l`

Got this:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xe9fded33

Device     Boot    Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *        2048    999423    997376  487M 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda2        1001470 137717759 136716290 65.2G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5        1001472  40060927  39059456 18.6G 83 Linux
/dev/sda6       40062976 137717759  97654784 46.6G 83 Linux

Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

BOOT-INFO

https://pastebin.com/BFUrL3cD

Boot repair says it succeeded, yet I still see only Ubuntu in the grub menu. Help please!

Comment: Who knows, simply stating that it is not working is insufficient information. Run boot-repair and send the url it provides if it fails. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I'm fairly certain that underneath `sudo update-grub` uses `os-prober`, but you might try it for good measure.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the *complete* link to the Boot-Info log? The current one just leads to the main page of the pastie service.

Comment: You sure that the Windows boot loader is present on the second disk?  If not you need to boot repair *just* that disk alone with the other drive disconnected and have the Windows boot loader restored.

Comment: @DavidFoerster: I was also confused by that, but all the boot repair gave me was "Please write on a paper the following URL: http://paste2.org/"

Comment: @ThomasWard: Sorry for the confusion, the second disk - sdb - is actually an external hard drive, and has nothing to do with my problem. I edited the code above to show that, running `sudo fdisk -l` after removing it.

Comment: I noticed another user with the same Boot-Info issue recently. If the provided pastie link doesn't work you can always save the log to a file and upload to a pastie service manually.

Comment: Yes, good suggestion. Post updated with the boot info.

Comment: Stupid question but did you accidentally destroy the windows bootloader partition that windows usually creates?  With no Bootloader detected Grub won't show Windows.

Comment: Quite possibly. Assuming this is the case, how should I proceed?

Comment: You need the Windows bootloader to boot Windows, AFAIK Grub only chain loads to it when present as opposed to replacing it

Comment: How do I reinstall the Windows bootloader? :(

Comment: Does this website seem like a good answer? https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/33433/restore-the-windows-boot-loader-after-an-ubuntu-update/ But if so, I don't have a Windows DVD (or at least, I don't think I have one). Where can I obtain said DVD?

Comment: @reincarnationofstackexchange You can download the ISO and burn to DVD or USB directly from Microsoft provided you have a valid license. Needless to say, Windows repairs are **off topic** in a Ubuntu related site.